# Can't login to game through google option

Tags: google-play-games

I can't login into Crusaders Quest through the google option, says network problem occured errorCode 4001. All other games login through this option just fine and I have a stable connection. What could be causing it?

Comment: Maybe the game it's just not doing good oauth authentication. Try to reinstall the game and login again.

Comment: Sadly that didn't fix it. Funny how the facebook login works fine everytime. Also it seems to affect king's raid and guardian soul aswell.

Comment: May be the devs didn't implement​ the auth correctly​. Ask them to help you.

Comment: It's not that either. The game logged in fine before but now it just doesn't want to.